# I have 1 pixel blank space between each borders of my table

Tags: css

[image]

As you can see on the picture above, I have 1 pixel space on each top-border and I don't know why.

Here is my css:

```
.aaa td
{
border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
```

I don't have this problem when copy/paste this table on jsfiddle.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 border-collapse: collapse;
```

Comment: I think `margin` is also worth mentioning.